# Program jumps alone from void loop() to another void

Tags: programming

```
//simple alarm system
int RipSensor1 = 12;
int RmkeyA = 3;
int RmkeyB = 5;
int RmkeyC = 6;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

void setup()
 {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RipSensor1,INPUT);
  pinMode(RmkeyA,INPUT);
  pinMode(RmkeyB,INPUT);
  pinMode(RmkeyC,INPUT);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.println(F("System Is Up & Running")); }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------

void loop()
 {
  Serial.println(F("Main Loop Start")); 
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);   //for debugging
  if (digitalRead(RmkeyA) == HIGH)
   {
    Rip1Status();
   }
 }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void AlarmSMS1()
 {
  //send sms to admin1
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));  
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));  
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Serial.println(F("SMS Sending to 1st ADMIN --->"));
  Rip1Status();   // return to this void (monitoring)
 }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

void Rip1Status()
 {
  Serial.println(F("VOID Rip1 Start..."));
  while (digitalRead(RmkeyB) == LOW) //Arm mode
   { 
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    if (digitalRead(RipSensor1) == HIGH) //when Rip sensor sense motion
     {
      Serial.println(F("Movement ALARM --> PowerUP Relay 1 & 2"));
      long RipTimer1 = 0;
      long Rip01 = 0;
      int z = 0;
      int x = 0;
      while (digitalRead(RmkeyC) == LOW)
       {
        RipTimer1++;  
        Serial.println(RipTimer1);   //for debugging
        if((z==0) && (RipTimer1 - Rip01 > 500))   //1st CheckPoint do something 
         {
          z = 1;
          Serial.println(F("1st CheckPoint OK"));
         }
        else if((x==0) && (RipTimer1 - Rip01 > 3000))   //2nd CheckPoint go on other void
         { 
          x = 1;
          AlarmSMS1();
         }
       }
      Serial.println(F("C Key Pressed --> False Alarm"));    //if button C pressed
      RipTimer1 = 0; 
      z = 0;
      x = 0;
      Serial.println(F("Monitoring Loop ends --> GoTo Main Loop"));  
      break;
     }
    else Serial.println(F("Monitoring"));  //for debugging
   }
  Serial.println(F("B Key Pressed --> Disarming"));  //for debugging
  Serial.println(F("Monitoring Loop ends --> GoTo Main Loop"));  
  loop();
 }
```

I make this code & i have this problem:
Program start & wait for A key pressed to Arm mode. works ok
Press A key go to Arm mode (monitoring). works ok
When its on "monitoring", if i press B key, system disarming then go to void loop() and wait. works ok
When its on "monitoring" & Rip sensor sense movement, then alarm start and if i press C key then disarming as false alarm and go to void loop() and wait. works ok
When its on "monitoring" & Rip sensor sense movement, if i left alarm to complete, go to sms void send sms to admin and return to Rip void (monitoring).
But on this point if i press B button to disarm system this happen...

```
Monitoring
Monitoring
Monitoring
Monitoring
Monitoring
Monitoring
Monitoring
Monitoring
Monitoring
Monitoring
B Key Pressed --> Disarming
Monitoring Loop ends --> GoTo Main Loop
Main Loop Start
3002
3003
3004
3005
3006
3007
3008
3009 
3010
3011
3012.............
```

Why this happen?
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: It's called a function not a void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loop()` calls `Rip1Status()`, which calls `loop()`, which calls `Rip1Status()`, which calls `loop`(), which calls ....

That process will continue until the stack overflows (runs out of memory) or over-writes some necessary variable. If you just meant for `Rip1Status()` to return to the main loop, delete the `loop()` call at the end of the function. When Rip1Status()`exits, control will automatically return to`loop()`at the statement following the`Rip1Status()` call.

Comment: JRobert. Same thing happen.

Comment: Same thing happen with you suggestion. RipTimer1 still count and program not stay on main loop. I try to redirect on other dummy void or break command but same think happen. Something big i missing here

Comment: JRobert thank you. After i read what you say many times finally i found the way. I have split Rip1Status() function in two. i have remove call function at the end of AlarmSMS1() and add return command on my code. Now works just fine. Thanks again....